# Negative coordinates in python Canvas

Tags: python

What would be the way to use negative coordinates in Canvas?

I try to create a line use:

```
`from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

cv = Canvas(master)
cv.create_line(0, 0, -100, -100)
cv.pack()

mainloop()`
```

But it doesn't works,

Is there any way to create a line with negative coordinates with Canvas in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: would `cv.configure(scrollregion = cv.bbox("ALL"))` work for you? Maybe the entire region isn't scrollable.

Comment: It works!! thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad! Please upvote / accept the answer below otherwise let us know if we can help otherwise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing the complete window scroll option :)

```
 cv.configure(scrollregion = cv.bbox("ALL"))
```